# how to select regex matches in jinja2?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, template-engine

### toy example

Essentially, I want to do something like:

```
['hello', 'apple', 'rare', 'trim', 'three'] | select(match('.*a[rp].*'))
```

Which would yield:

```
['apple', 'rare']
```

### what am I talking about?

The [`match`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters) filter and [`select`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#select) filter. My issue arises from the fact that the select filter only supports unary "tests".

I'm on Ansible 1.9.x.

### my actual use case

...is closer to:

```
lookup('dig', ip_address, qtype="PTR", wantList=True) | select(match("mx\\..*\\.example\\.com"))
```

So, I want to get all the PTR records associated with an IP and then filter out all the ones that don't fit a given regex. I'd also want to ensure that there's only one element in the resulting list, and output that element, but that's a different concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This design pattern worked for me:

```
----
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    my_list: ['hello', 'apple', 'rare', 'trim', "apropos", 'three']
    my_pattern: 'a[rp].*'
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        matches: "{%- set tmp = [] -%}
                  {%- for elem in my_list | map('match', my_pattern) | list -%}
                    {%- if elem -%}
                      {{ tmp.append(my_list[loop.index - 1]) }}
                    {%- endif -%}
                  {%- endfor -%}
                  {{ tmp }}"
    - debug:
        var: matches
      failed_when: "(matches | length) > 1"
```

Comment: I found this answer helpful in that it allowed me to believe that a parameterized `filter` really is missing, which I found hard to believe. This is disgusting, but at least it did the trick and let me move on...

Comment: `This is disgusting` No argument here. This much general-purpose programming in a template is definitely an antipattern. When I did this I opened an issue ticket in my backlog to move that logic somewhere else. Thankfully I virtually never have to open a ticket like that.

Comment: @ParthianShot The above code will raise a `TemplateRuntimeError` exception cause `match` is not a filter.
Also as mentioned in the answer before yours, I don't understand why you raise an error  it the matches list contains more than one element (`failed_when: "(matches | length) > 1"`), which makes the playbook fail when it works

Comment: Worth noting that I wrote this answer in 2016, and even for that time I wasn't using the most recent version of ansible. This solution may only work for a version of ansible 1.x, since the ansible 2.x upgrade broke everything.

Comment: @ParthianShot, I don't know much jinja or python, but programming in Ansible is an anti-pattern.  Mostly when you have to manipulate text that far, Ansible may not be your best tool.

Answer (score 16):

Will this do?

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    my_list: ['hello', 'apple', 'rare', 'trim', 'three']
    my_pattern: '.*a[rp].*'
  tasks:
    - set_fact: matches="{{ my_list | map('regex_search',my_pattern) | select('string') | list }}"
      failed_when: matches | count > 1
    - debug: msg="I'm the only one - {{ matches[0] }}"
```

Update: how it works...

- [map](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#map) applies **filters** – filters are not yes/no things, they applied to
  every item of input list and return list of modified items. I use
  `regex_search` filter, which search pattern in every item and return
  a match if found or None if there is no match. So on this step I get
  this list: `[null, "apple", "rare", null, null]`.
- Then we use [select](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#select), which applies **tests** – tests are yes/no things, so
  they reduce the list based on selected test. I use `string` test, which is
  true when item of a list is string. So we get: `["apple", "rare"]`.
- `map` and `select` give us some internal python types, so we convert to list
  by applying `list` filter after all.

Comment: Nope. For one thing, `regex_search` doesn't exist; you'd just use `search`. For another, `map` returns a list of booleans, here, so `select('string')` will always yield an empty list.

Comment: Argh, missed that you are on 1.9... Switch to modern tools :)

Comment: Why `map` returns a list of booleans? It applies a filter and give you a list of filtered items. In my example it gives you strings where match found and null where no match found.

Comment: The idea behind a regex `search` or regex `match` is that you want to know whether something appeared in a search, or whether it matched. Since those are yes / no questions, the answer in each case is a boolean. However, if you want to replace instead, you'd do something like a `regex_replace`.

Comment: @ParthianShot i've updated my answer with some explanation.

Comment: I know what `map` does. That's not the issue. Map applies a function to every element of its input, and the set of outputs from that function are the output from map. `search` in 1.9 does not output string / null, it outputs True / False. There isn't anything in ansible (1.9 or 2.0) called `regex_search`. You have invented this function.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I don't understand why you raise an error  it the matches list contains more than one element (`failed_when: matches | count > 1`), this makes the playbook fail when it works

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that in 2020 something like `my_list | select('match', my_pattern) | list` is sufficient. Since you used a similar direct approach in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47172722/427158) I'm wondering - was match/search just added in some later Ansible 2 version?

Answer (score 4):

I found the following trick if you want to filter a list in Ansible (get the list with null values and make difference with null list) :

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    regexp: '.*a[rp].*'
    empty: [null]
  tasks:
    - set_fact: matches="{{ ['hello', 'apple', 'rare', 'trim', 'three'] | map('regex_search',regexp)  | list|difference(empty) }}"
    - debug: msg="{{ matches }}"
```

Here is the output :

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "apple", 
        "rare"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [select](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#select) like this:

```
['hello', 'apple', 'rare', 'trim', 'three'] | select('match', '.*a[rp]')
```

Which would yield:

```
['apple', 'rare']
```

The [match](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) uses the [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) implementation and hence matches at beginning of string. Therefore you need `.*` at beginning, but not at the end of the regexp.

Or you can use `search` to avoid `.*` altogether:

```
['hello', 'apple', 'rare', 'trim', 'three'] | select('search', 'a[rp]')
```