# ansible filter list when matches

Tags: ansible

With `groups.all` that returns a list with all hosts in inventory, is it possible to extract the ones contains unique string into another list.

When I debug `groups.all` I get following list with all hosts in inventory.

```
"groups.all": [
    "host-1-unique",
    "host-2",
    "host-3",
    "host-4-unique",
    "host-5",
    "host-6-unique",
    "host-7"
],
```

In my main.yml

```
- set_fact:
  new_list: []

- set_fact: "{{ new_list }} + [ '{{ item }}' ]"
  with_items: groups.all
  when: 'unique' in groups.all
```

and I get following result:

```
{
    "skipped": true,
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",
    "_ansible_item_result": true,
    "item": "groups.all",
    "changed": false
}
```

Does anyone know why this's been skipped? 
How do I extract from a list, that returns list of elements with unique string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to learn about Jinja2 [filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#filters) (built-in and Ansible supplied).

```
- set_fact:
    new_list: "{{ groups['all'] | select('search','unique') | list }}"
```