# In ansible how do print stderr of each item which fails in a task?

Tags: ansible

I have an array of servers provided by user input, I want to test each server in the list, if any fail i would like to know which ones failed and why (stderr). Note, the number of servers will not be consistent, so the solution needs to by dynamic in the number of servers being sent.

Command

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -e '{"chrony_servers":["0.centos.pool.ntp.org","10.centos.pool.ntp.org"]}'
```

Test.yml

```
- name: Services Playbook
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

  - name: Install nmap-ncat
    yum: name=nc state=present

  - name: Validate chrony_servers
    command: nc -vzu {{ item }} 123
    with_items:
      - "{{ chrony_servers }}"
    ignore_errors: yes
    register: chrony_server_results

  - debug: var=chrony_server_results

  - fail:
      msg: "{{ chrony_server_results.results.stderr }}"
    when: chrony_server_results.failed is defined and chrony_server_results.failed == true
```

This is the output that comes from this example

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "chrony_server_results": {
        "changed": true,
        "failed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": true,
                "_ansible_item_label": "0.centos.pool.ntp.org",
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_parsed": true,
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": [
                    "nc",
                    "-vzu",
                    "0.centos.pool.ntp.org",
                    "123"
                ],
                "delta": "0:00:02.217171",
                "end": "2019-05-16 18:58:54.070600",
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "nc -vzu 0.centos.pool.ntp.org 123",
                        "_uses_shell": false,
                        "argv": null,
                        "chdir": null,
                        "creates": null,
                        "executable": null,
                        "removes": null,
                        "stdin": null,
                        "warn": true
                    }
                },
                "item": "0.centos.pool.ntp.org",
                "rc": 0,
                "start": "2019-05-16 18:58:51.853429",
                "stderr": "Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )\nNcat: Connected to 208.75.88.4:123.\nNcat: UDP packet sent successfully\nNcat: 1 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 2.21 seconds.",
                "stderr_lines": [
                    "Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )",
                    "Ncat: Connected to 208.75.88.4:123.",
                    "Ncat: UDP packet sent successfully",
                    "Ncat: 1 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 2.21 seconds."
                ],
                "stdout": "",
                "stdout_lines": []
            },
            {
                "_ansible_item_label": "10.centos.pool.ntp.org",
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_parsed": true,
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": [
                    "nc",
                    "-vzu",
                    "10.centos.pool.ntp.org",
                    "123"
                ],
                "delta": "0:00:00.312970",
                "end": "2019-05-16 18:58:54.510976",
                "failed": true,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "nc -vzu 10.centos.pool.ntp.org 123",
                        "_uses_shell": false,
                        "argv": null,
                        "chdir": null,
                        "creates": null,
                        "executable": null,
                        "removes": null,
                        "stdin": null,
                        "warn": true
                    }
                },
                "item": "10.centos.pool.ntp.org",
                "msg": "non-zero return code",
                "rc": 2,
                "start": "2019-05-16 18:58:54.198006",
                "stderr": "Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )\nNcat: Could not resolve hostname \"10.centos.pool.ntp.org\": Name or service not known. QUITTING.",
                "stderr_lines": [
                    "Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )",
                    "Ncat: Could not resolve hostname \"10.centos.pool.ntp.org\": Name or service not known. QUITTING."
                ],
                "stdout": "",
                "stdout_lines": []
            }
        ]
    }
}

TASK [fail] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'stderr'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/vera/test.yml': line 14, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  - debug: var=chrony_server_results\n  - fail:\n    ^ here\n"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/vera/test.retry

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
```

The Expected result should be something like

```
"stderr": "Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )\nNcat: Could not resolve hostname \"10.centos.pool.ntp.org\": Name or service not known. QUITTING."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of your `chrony_server_results` is a dictionary, with a bit different structure than your debug task is assuming.
It has some keys on the top level, that apply to the task that you are invoking `with_items` as a whole, like `changed` and `failed`.
The "subresults" for the individual invocations, which contain the respective `stderr` and `rc` properties, are stored in an array that has the key `results`.
This means that `chrony_server_results.results.stderr` is wrong, and the error tells you that this array does not have a `stderr` property, rather there are multiple of those for the individual entries, over which you need to iterate.
You could check the `rc` to know if the respective invocation *actually* failed (since netcat apparently writes to stderr in all cases).

The following solution first builds an array that contains only the results that have an `rc` greater than zero, and then shows a debug message for only those results:

```
 - set_fact:
     failed_results: "{{ chrony_server_results.results | selectattr('rc', '>', 0) | list }}"

 - name: Show the stderrs of failed_results
   debug:
     msg: "{{ item.stderr }}"
   with_items: "{{ failed_results }}"

  - fail:
      msg: "See debug output above"
    when: failed_results | length > 0
```

The filter that is being used in the first expression is part of jinja2, and documented here: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#selectattr

Comment: I see what you are saying here.  However the results still fail to print in this example.  It might be easier to use the key attr "failed" and filter the results which are "failed" : "true"

Comment: I didn't even notice that the results also have a `failed` property. I cannot actually try it out right now. What is the error message? Maybe try it with `selectattr('failed', 'equalto', false)`, possible with `| list`?added

Comment: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'stderr'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/vera/test.yml': line 20, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Show the stderrs of failed_results\n    ^ here\n"
}

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47172265/ansible-filter-list-when-matches#answer-47172722). I also updated my post.